# Django - Redirecting from trailing slash to non-trailing slash

Tags: django

I like how Django redirects from `/some/url` to `/some/url/` when I use regex `^/some/url/$`, but it doesn't do vice versa, e.g. redirecting from `/some/url/` to `/some/url` when I use regex `^/some/url$`.

How could I add this feature from inside of my django app instead of using manual mod_rewrite?

Comment: Don't. ULRs should end in slashes, if they don't refer to actual files.

Comment: @Daniel I'd rather see trailing slash when a page is a list or 'folder' of articles and no trailing slash when a page is a single article. E.g. `/category/` for list of articles and `/category/article-title` for single article. It gives users info about what type of page they can expect.

Comment: possible duplicate of [django urls without a trailing slash do not redirect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1596552/django-urls-without-a-trailing-slash-do-not-redirect)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've got it working. I've added `/?` to my URL RegEx, right before the `$` sign at the end. Then I've added this to my `views.py`:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect
# ...
def some_view(request, some_param):
    if request.path[-1] == '/':
        return redirect(request.path[:-1])
    # ...
```