# Django - Reverse resolution of URL throws 'NoReverseMatch'

Tags: python, django

I have `url(r'^topics/(?P<topic_id>\d+)/$', views.topic, name='topic')` in urls.py but when I try to go to localhost:8000/topics/1 it tells me that it tried one pattern: `topics/(?P<topic_id>**\\**d+)/$`
I would think it would be `topics/(?P<topic_id>**\**d+)/$`

I'm using a book called **The Python Crash Course** (1st edition)(ch. 18).
This is a local server using Django 1.11 with Python. I've tried a lot of reformatting on the url pattern but I am new at this so I don't know what else to do.

```py
...
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),

    # Show all topics.
    url(r'^topics/$', views.topics, name='topics'),

    # Detail page for a single topic.
    url(r'^topics/(?P<topic_id>\d+)/$', views.topic, name='topic'),
]
```

I expected it to pop up with the correct page but it always says '***NoReverseMatch at /topics/01/***'

Comment: `localhost:8000/topics/1` You're not forgetting the trailing slash?

Comment: sorry, yes I am.

Answer (score 1):

So you've **forgotten the trailing slash** at the end of your URL, hence why it's not matching.

You could remove the slash from the regex, but that would shift the problem: it wouldn't work if you put a slash.

I guess you could end the pattern with `/?$`, but here's a solution that's probably more robust: [Jiaaro's answer to: django urls without a trailing slash do not redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1596600/1899494)

Basically:

> check your **APPEND_SLASH** setting in the settings.py file