# Django | Cannot access URLs without a trailing "/"

Tags: python, django

I have a Django application where, for some reason, I cannot load my URLs without a trailing "/"

I have other Django applications I've made in practice where this hasn't been an issue, and I don't need one when I go to my Admin page, so I can't figure out what's setup wrong here.

Here's my main URLs file:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('app/', include('app.urls')),
]
```

Here's my app's URLs file:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('subapp/', views.subapp, name='subapp'),
]
```

And my views file:

```
def subapp(request):
    return render(request, 'app/subapp.html', {'title': 'subapp'})
```

When I enter my URL as "localhost:8000/app/subapp/" it takes me to the correct page.

However, when I enter my URL as "localhost:8000/app/subapp" I get a 404 with the following debug error message: `Directory indexes are not allowed here.`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your path `subapp/` has a slash at the end.

Comment: @KlausD. Yes, but I have CommonMiddleware going, so it should append the slash, shouldn't it?  I want there to be a slash, because the issue is, if I go to "localhost:8000/app" without the slash, it also won't load...  On my other Django projects, the slash is appended.

Answer (score 4):

Please check APPEND_SLASH setting in the settings.py file.

Please also check that link:

[django urls without a trailing slash do not redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1596552/django-urls-without-a-trailing-slash-do-not-redirect)

Comment: I had checked this, but for my specific use case, it was because I was missing
```MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')```and
```MEDIA_URL = '/media/'```

Answer (score 0):

For my specific usecase, it was because I needed to add the following to my settings.py:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

This fixed my issue.