# Request URL: Category 404

Tags: python, django

I have, Page not found (404) when accessing `/category/Django`

urls.py

```
from .views import (
    PostListViewHome,
    CategoryView,

)

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("", PostListViewHome.as_view(), name="Blog-home"),  
    path("category/<str:cats>/", views.CategoryView, name="category"),
]
```

views.py

```
def CategoryView(request, cats):
    category_posts = Post.objects.filter(category=cats)
    return render(request, 'Blog/category.html', {'cats':cats, 'category_posts':category_posts})
```

urls.py in the MPIE02

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from django.urls import path, include
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView
from users import views as user_views
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
          path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(template_name='users/logout.html'), name='Logout'),
    path('', include ('Blog.urls')),
]


if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

if i try to accessing  /category/ it showin me just 404

Comment: where you are getting that error

Comment: when I go to http://xxxx/category/Django/

Comment: please provide settings file

Comment: I add it to the post

Comment: Please consider following recommended [naming convention](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/internals/contributing/writing-code/coding-style/). And avoid sharing your SECRET_KEY and other sensitive data.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [django urls without a trailing slash do not redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1596552/django-urls-without-a-trailing-slash-do-not-redirect)

Comment: now this showed up; Field 'id' expected a number but got 'Django'.

Comment: There is no `id` reference in shown code, so the error is somewhere else. Or this is not the actual code. Since 404 issue solved please ask another question with the current problem and code.

Comment: You should show the content of this file: `MPIE02/urls.py` and tell the result of accessing `/category/`

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/internals/contributing/writing-code/coding-style/

Comment: the MPIE02/urls.py is there

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because in your settings file, there is no any path added of templates.

Add path in settings file:

```
 import os
    TEMPLATES = [
        {
            'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
            'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'appname','templates',)],
            'APP_DIRS': True,
            'OPTIONS': {
                'context_processors': [
                    'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                    'django.template.context_processors.request',
                    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                ],
            },
        },
    ]
```

Comment: It didn't work, same error.

Comment: Is that templates inside app please tell me

Comment: now telling me; Field 'id' expected a number but got 'Django'.

Comment: please paste error

Comment: `ValueError at /category/Django/`

Comment: and, `Field 'id' expected a number but got 'Django'.`

Comment: you are getting this error from model provide models also

Comment: `class Post(models.Model): 
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)
        verbose_name = 'category'
        verbose_name_plural = 'categories'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name`

Comment: the models working just fine