# More elegant one-liner way for urls.py to recognize path that include / as well as no / in Django

Tags: python, django, django-urls, django-4.0

I am using Django v4. This is my `urls.py`

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import UserList, UserDetail

urlpatterns = [
    path("users", UserList.as_view()),
]
```

`http://127.0.0.1:8000/users` works fine. However, `http://127.0.0.1:8000/users/` with the slash at the end fails to work.

To solve this problem, here's the new `urls.py`.

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import UserList, UserDetail

urlpatterns = [
    path("users", UserList.as_view()),
    path("users/", UserList.as_view()),
]
```

It looks kind of repetitive and goes against DRY principle behind Django. Is there a more elegant one-liner to fix this problem?
Answer need not be a one-liner as long as it doesn't look repetitive.

EDIT: Best answer I found is here [django urls without a trailing slash do not redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1596552/django-urls-without-a-trailing-slash-do-not-redirect/1596600#1596600)

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1596552/django-urls-without-a-trailing-slash-do-not-redirect  for a solution. but you should redirect from one to the other.  no reason to create ambiguity for such a corner case.

Comment: Thanks. Updated my question to show the answer you posted.

Answer (score -1):

```
path("users/", UserList.as_view())
```

This should cater for both the trailing slash